# What is the best way to separate projects in AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to have a strict split between my own, personal, services in the AWS. These services can be split into two categories:

- Ones that are not changing often but are responsible for crucial for me services (e.g. Route53 config for my main domain),
- Ones that are "experiments" / side-projects that can change often and touches multiple services through CloudFront/Serverless framework.

What is the best solution in 2021 to address this challenge? Multiple AWS accounts or AWS Organizations or something else?

The requirements are:

- I would like to have my crucial services (first category of services) properly guarded, i.e. not easily changed by a mistake,
- At the same time I'm the only person that will in the end manage both so I'd like to have one bill and not separate ones.

Comment: Usually ppl use AWS Organization with multiple accounts.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. So a separate AWS Account and gathered under umbrella of AWS Organization? Or 3 accounts (main, the one that 'manages' AWS Organization only and two for the actual services?)

Comment: Yes. So you can have 1 AWS Org, with 1 management account (the main), and the 2 member accounts for your services. Depending how you wan to work, you can have also a third account for security where are your logs will end up from the member accounts.

Comment: That's swell and seems to suffice all my needs and keep the accounts together (which I was missing with the idea of totally separate accounts). Feel free to move it to an answer so I can accept it if you like. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Answer provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to address your use-case is through [AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_introduction.html). Using AWS Org you would have one [management account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_getting-started_concepts.html) and two [member accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_getting-started_concepts.html) for your services.

This allows you to consolidate all the billing as well as setup Org level [Service control policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) to manage permissions in your member account.

It is also common to have  a dedicated [security member account](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/best-practices-for-organizational-units-with-aws-organizations/) which will be a central repository of various logs from other accounts.